# Why is JavaScript geolocation only Approximate?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

No matter how I use the JavaScript:

```
position.coords.latitude;
position.coords.longitude;
```

The returned coordinates are always at least a few city blocks off.
So - it will show the "start point" or "Your location" as a few streets over?

This approximate result seems new, as the code I used before produced a more accurate result.

I have tested on all browser's from a "https" web page.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + '/' + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Has something changed?
Why is the produced coordinates only approximate?

Comment: Why do you expect them to be more accurate than that?

Comment: What kind of device are you running the code on? Unless it has GPS, it's using geolocation that may be based on IP address ranges or the location of wifi hotspots.

Comment: @Pointy It used to be very accurate. To within a meter or 2.

Comment: @Barmar I have tested on all browser's from a "https" web page, and multiple mobile device types, android, apple.

Comment: The way geolocation works is a patchwork of local GPS (if available, like on phones), IP-based location (always basically a guess), and things like that. It cannot be relied upon for extreme accuracy like delivering a pizza to somebody.

Comment: @Pointy So how do applications like Uber do it? They tell the driver your exact location.

Comment: @pointy ok - so, if you then click on the start location in the opened map (either web or if you let the app open google map) it allows you the option to change the start point choice of clicking on "your location" if you click that - the start location is readjusted and it is extremely accurate to within a few feet. Why does it go from "basically a guess" to extremely accurate?

Comment: @Barmar if you use Uber a lot you learn to message the driver your exact location ("SE corner of Scum Street and 3rd") because the geolocation cannot be trusted.

Comment: @TV-C-1-5 if you are standing outside, with a phone with built-in GPS, and you're not in a central business district with lots of tall buildings, it will be accurate. If you are on a laptop in a rural area, it won't be very accurate.

Comment: @Pointy I don't use it alot (actually I use Lyft, but I assume they're the same), but I've never had to call the driver to give them my location. It asks me where the pickup is, and it's always my actual address.

Comment: Inaccurate location (with Lyft) has definitely happened to me, standing outside with a phone with GPS. I mean, even when it's vaguely close I consider that to be pretty cool, but as I said, it was a lesson learned.\

Comment: @pointy you did not address the issue where if you then click on the option of "your location" the accuracy of the start point is then pinpoint. Wat would be the discrepancy here I wonder?

Comment: And what does the map app show on the phone? Is it off?

Comment: @TV-C-1-5 "click on the option of 'your location'" -- click where? What option, in what context?

Comment: @Pointy - as I said, when a map opens, there is the 'to' and 'from' location. The from location always allows you to make a selection of "Your location" - when you click that - the 'from' point now becomes pin-point accurate. Why would that be pinpoint, if your location is as you said "always basically a guess" ?

Comment: @epascarello - I'm not sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tradeoff between speed and accuracy. [Gelocation.getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) at MDN details the optional parameter `enableHighAccuracy`

Comment: I tried this, although the returned coordinates were slightly different - it was still off by pretty much the same distance. It only made a difference of a few feet.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript geolocation is only an approximation of the device's actual location because it relies on the device's built-in GPS, Wi-Fi, IP address lookup and/or network triangulation to determine your location. Additionally, the Geolocation API provides an estimated location, **not an exact location**. The accuracy of the location information can vary greatly and can be influenced by various factors, including the type of device, its settings, and the environment (buildings, trees, etc) in which it is used.

I used your function and indeed the latitude and longitude coordinates were not exact, there is a difference of a few meters (more than 30-40).

Comment: Any sources for you comments?

Comment: Google is full of resources https://www.maptoaster.com/maptoaster-topo-nz/articles/how-gps-works/how-gps-works.html